# Why am I getting InvalidUseOfMatchers build error here?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, matcher

This code compiles and debugs well, but when I do a maven build in Eclipse the unit test and the build fails. I don't understand where is the misuse of the matchers here? Thanks.

[ERROR] Errors: [ERROR]   Tests.MyTest() » InvalidUseOfMatchers

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MapperFactory.class})
public class Tests {
  @Mock private Bucket bucketMock;
  @Mock private MutateInBuilder builderMock;
  @InjectMocks private Repository couchbaseRepository;
  private MapperFactory mapperFactory;

  @Autowired
  public void setMapperFactory(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
    this.mapperFactory = mapperFactory;
  }
  @Test
  public void MyTest() throws MyException {
    String jsonText = jsonSamples.getProperty("theJson");
    Mapper mapper = mapperFactory.getMapper(JsonObject.fromJson(jsonText),repository);    

   when(bucketMock.mutateIn("1234")).thenReturn(builderMock);
   mapper.execute();
   verify(builderMock).execute();
 }
}
```

Comment: Is that *all* the exception says? Just "InvalidUseOfMatchers"? Or is there more explanation? Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: (I'll admit it's not really clear to me what you're trying to test here...)

Comment: Can you please past the whole stacktrace or error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, that right, that was all the exception was saying. The solution was to update the artifactId of Mockito in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

was replaced with:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```